# Whose avatar was tembe swAmi?

Tags: avatars, tradition

Tembe swami (vAsudevananda saraswati) , was a well known figure in Maharashtra.

Whose avatar is he considered as ?

Comment: If you run short of Saints' names in future, ping me, i can supply a few.

Comment: Dattatreya. He was from Advaita Sampradaya.